# Where should I set the animation flag bool back to false?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the top of the script :

```
public bool useJump = false;
public Vector3 jump;
public float jumpImpulse;

private bool isGrounded;
private Rigidbody rb;
private Animator anim;
```

In the Start()

```
void Start()
        {
            anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
            mainCamera = Camera.main;
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
        }
```

OnCollisionStay

```
private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
```

In the Update()

```
private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J) && isGrounded && useJump)
            {
                anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
                rb.AddForce(jump * jumpImpulse, ForceMode.Impulse);
                isGrounded = false;
            }
        }
```

In the Animator Controller in the editor I have a new state I named it "Jump" with the jump animation.

I added two transitions from the "Jump" state to the Locomotion blend tree and back from the Locomotion tree to the "Jump" state.

Also added a parameter type bool name Jump

I unchecked false in both transitions the Has Exit Time and added Conditions for both transitions the one from the Locomotion to the "Jump" is true and from the "Jump" to the Locomotion it's set to false.

The problem is where in the script I set it back to false ?
How do I know when the state "Jump" has finished playing ?

I can't figure out where to set it back to false :

```
anim.SetBool("Jump", false);
```

[Jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/573E3.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you use Trigger for jumping? It will only place the animation once and return back to Locomotion when it finished Jumping.

Comment: @MuhammadHämzãTàhïr Trigger it is. Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadHämzãTàhïr What about if I want the jumping to be with the player moving walking animation the same time ? Now when I press J for jumping the player stop and jump but if I want that when I'm pressing on W to walk forward and than pressing on J so it will keep walk and jump ?

Comment: Are you using trigger now? If you are not using `Apple Root Motion`, then the `GameObject` is not affected by animations. You have to keep adding forward force while the player is jumping to make it move forward while jumping.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `anim.SetBool("Jump", false);` in the OnCollisionStay trigger, and see if that works.

I recommend that since every frame the player is touching the ground, it will be set to false, but as soon as he jumps, the bool will be set to true and thus, the player animation will be played.